# the following modules appear to be missing with py2exe

Tags: python-2.7, py2exe

I have tried both ways with the setup py2exe file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(    windows=[{"script":"fisherexchart.py"}])
```

and the other way of:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(=['fisherexchart.py'])
```

Both of which ways seem to be giving me the same errors of missing files. Ive used py2exe and never come across this but updated to windows 10 recently. No idea of what's gone wrong!

[image]

Any help would be appreciated people.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a lot easier using pyinstaller:

```
pyinstaller.exe nameofscript.py
```